# 20.04/Windows 10 dual boot: Ubuntu not booting after loading Windows 10 for the first time (Initramfs loading failed)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, boot-repair, initramfs

I did some Googling. I saw some mention of windows not having access to ext4 (via Ext2File or such) AFAIK I have no such apps installed. Not sure where to begin. I currently can't even boot Ubuntu. [See full error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsAIK.jpg)

BootInfo summary from boot repair on a USB drive: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DvwQkrms25/

Comment: To add to this, Windows 10 is able to boot fine. Seems Grub is working but neither the boot option for Ubuntu nor ubuntu (recovery) work

Comment: Looks like an older UEFI/BIOS. Is there an update, if so install it as early UEFI implementations often had issues. Even then some need boot parameters. Is this Intel or AMD based system? Some use acpi=off  boot parameter. Some others have needed various UEFI settings like Windows 7 mode, external SATA off or others.

Comment: It's an intel cpu core i5 4670. Although I'm upgrading to a new motherboard/CPU soon so I might just wait until afterwards and reinstall Ubuntu altogether. I did try with ACPI off and it didn't help. Was working fine until I booted Windows on my other drive for the first time.

Comment: I have similar Haswell system, but no Windows. UUIDs look correct, not really seening anything wrong. What video card do you have?

Comment: It's a GTX 1070. Just updated my sustem to a B365 mbb/9400F and an NVME m.2 ssd recently. Giving a fresh Ubuntu install a try now. Will see if booting windows causes issues again and report back.

Comment: Make sure UEFI & SSD firmware are up two date (even if new). Some settings in UEFI and maybe boot parameters are required depending on brand. You want to boot installer in UEFI boot mode and then had UEFI set for UEFI only, but Secure Boot off. And use gpt partitioning.